# Why don't we say: "The shop is opened"?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, passive-voice

Why do we write "The shop is open" and not "The shop is opened"?

The passive voice is formed this way: *verb* + *ed*.
On the other hand, we write "The shop is closed".

Comment: "The shop is opened by Tom" is the passive version of "Tom opens the shop".

Comment: Also related: *[“All opened files” or “all open files”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234480)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider both examples:

> The shop is closed.

> The shop is open.

In this case, "open" and "closed" are adjectives. The word "closed" is an example of a participial adjective. It is similar to others such as "surprised", "intrigued", and "tired". These adjectives usually come from words with Latin roots. Other adjectives, such as "open" and "bright", have Germanic roots and do not take English forms requiring "ed" at the end.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 'Closed' is on occasion a past participle: _The shop is closed at 10 pm on weekdays_.

Answer (score 1):

"Open" and "Closed" are both adjectives describing the shop.

It's just one of those situations where a verb matches the adjectives one way but not for its opposite. You wouldn't say "the shop is close," since the adjective close has a completely different definition.