# Why do we use open and closed instead of opened and closed

Tags: phrase-usage

(Originally posted in Linguistics but I was told here is more appropriate)

When talking about a door, for example, we usually say:

"the door is open" and "the door is closed"

why don't we say:

"the door is opened" and "the door is closed" ?

Comment: Dunno if it's directly relevant, but it's interesting to consider the "comparitive adjective" forms ***opener*** and ***closer*** (in the context of comparing two doors, say, one of which is "more ajar" than the other). It's at the margins of "credible usage", but I'm more or less okay with saying one door is ***opener*** than the other. I'd find it a bit harder to say the other's ***closer***, but consider [*(among) different RP speakers, closer and opener varieties (of this sound are) quite common.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22speakers%2C+closer+and+opener+varieties+being%22)

Comment: (And would that be an ***s*** or a ***z*** phonetically? How about ***closeder**?*)

Comment: Comparatives of participles are usually not morphological. There's already a word _opener_, for instance; it's a noun. And _open_ doesn't end in /i/ or /o/, so _more open_ is what the rule produces. _Closeder_ is very odd -- the /zd/ right before the suffix feels wrong, like the syllable's too heavy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Both "opener" and "closeder" would violate the rule that only monosyllabic comparatives can take the "-er" suffix. I've found this to be a pretty robust rule in AmE. Is BrE more flexible with regards to this?

Comment: @AzorAhai: That's a reasonable "rule of thumb", but there are quite a few exceptions, and a *lot* of "marginal" cases (nobody would argue with ***easier, narrower, unhappier***, for example). Not to mention which ***closed*** is monosyllabic anyway. I doubt there's any significant US/UK split though.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235591/why-dont-we-say-the-shop-is-opened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principal answer to almost all "why" questions about language is "because that's the way it is".

Sometimes, though, you can find a historical explanation of how things came to be - which does not answer the question "why", but can give some understanding.

In this case, the historical reason seems to be that the verb *open* comes from the adjective *open* (probably not in English, but in a prior state of the language). So *open* has had the adjectival meaning longer than it has been used as a verb.

In the case of *close*, though it seems to come ultimately from a Latin adjective (past participle *clausum*), within English (and the French we got it from) it was primarily a verb, and so the derived *closed* came into use.  There is another reason as well: There *is* an adjective *close* in English - from the same root - and it has retained a few special uses with the meaning *closed*, as in *close season*; but in general it has taken the different meaning (and pronunciation) *close* = "near"), and the meaning *shut* is no longer available for the word.